Уведомление при входе на полигон mapkit sdk
У меня есть, карта mapkit sdk, есть отдельный файл UserLocation на отображение местоположения пользователя и есть полигоны (Polygons).
Также есть нижнее меню навигации где расположены Карта (MapFragment), Профиль (ProfileFragment) и Жалобы (ComplaintFragment).
Я хотел бы реализовать такую вещь, как уведомление для пользователя если он зашел на полигон, но ума не приложу как это сделать. Возможно конечно реально еще сделать, уведомление при входе в полигон будучи если ты в разделе карты, но хочется просто уведомлять народ даже если они не на карте или даже если у них заблокирован телефон, уведомлять о том, что они вошли на определенный полигон.
Я подумал о том, чтобы сделать радиус вокруг местоположения пользователя и если этот круг радиуса задевает границу полигона то присылать уведомление, однако это будет работать только на карте, а как сделать если пользователь будет в другом месте приложения или вообще экран на блокировке не знаю.
Скажите реально это сделать или нет, с чего начать ?
Может быть моя версия ошибочна и есть другие предложения, скажите куда двигаться.

Отслеживание геолокации пользователя в фоне возможно только в коммерческой версии MapKit SDK.
Для реализации уведомлений для пользователя необходимо, чтобы приложение запрашивало в ОС право на постоянный мониторинг локации устройства, а также возможность отправлять нотификации.
По вопросу определения попадания координат пользователя в полигон — таких возможностей в MapKit SDK нет. Аналогичную задачу вы можете решить с помощью JavaScript API, в качестве основы вы можете использовать пример Проверка адреса на попадание в зону доставки.
